# face recognition as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flexbuilder, face-recognition

I want to build flash application that can detect the user eyes color and hair color etc'
Does anyone know about free library that I can use for this kind of project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of visual processing is generally too intense to handle within the single thread and VM that AS3 provides, it's a task better suited to a language that compiles to machine code and has threading capabilities such as C or C++.

Here's something related to the topic, I believe you would be better off just trying to use OpenCV, but it should also contain the appropriate algorithms to port if you have the time and mental capacity to do so: http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php

Alternatively to avoid all the leg-work you may want to consider using a server side solution like http://face.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this library:

http://code.google.com/p/face-recognition-library-as3/

Never tried it myself, but this [demo](http://vimeo.com/13466389) looks promising.

Comment: That library only had one contributor and all the comments are in polish, plus, the best I've seen in AS3 for face recognition is very crude, I doubt it will be able to distinguish eyes and hair color.  Good to suggest but I doubt if this will have the abilities requested.

Answer (score 1):

shaunhusain I think that you mistook face detection for face recognition although [face-recognition-library-as3](http://code.google.com/p/face-recognition-library-as3/) enables both. Comments in source files of library are in Polish for now, but there is documentation in English available online for that library.

In answer to main question of this thread it should be possible to detect only eyes using this library. To do that you should replace HaarCascades in face.zip file to those for detecting eyes, which are part of OpenCV. To detect hair color you could detect face and then analyze pixels just above detected region with face.

Hope that helps.